# SQL AND Operator In Searching For Column Selected

Tags: sql, and-operator

In this example from http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp

```
SELECT * 
FROM Customers
WHERE Country='Germany'
AND City='Berlin';
```

you can search for when multiple items are listed under certain columns.  What would the code be if you wanted to search for what is under a certain column AND when a certain column is selected?  For instance, in the attached example say we'd want to know when the country is Germany AND that "Country" is also selected (as opposed to they city).

Comment: It would be the same - which columns you `SELECT` has nothing to with the `WHERE` clause. In the above example, *all* columns are selected. Or is that not what you mean?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by *is under a certain column* and by *when a certain column is selected*?

Comment: It's not that the city is selected in the example, but that all columns (`*`) from the `Customers` table are returned, as long as the `Country` column is `'Germany'` **AND** the `City` column is `'Berlin'`.

Answer (score 1):

Just for clarification, I think that you're misunderstanding the `WHERE` line in:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Customers
WHERE Country='Germany'
AND City='Berlin';
```

The AND is part of the WHERE. Let me write it like this, maybe that clears things up:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Customers
WHERE (
    Country='Germany'
      AND
    City='Berlin'
)
;
```

Answer (score -1):

In a SQL request, there is a clear distinction between the SELECT clause and the WHERE one.

The SELECT clause is used to decided what information has to be returned from the query.

The WHERE clause is used to filter the information that will be returned (from the select clause) based on operator.

So in your case, since you want to know when the country is germany when the country is also into the select, you can simply do:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Country='Germany'
```

There is no way in SQL to have what you need, this should be handle by the piece of code (or you) that is reponsible for creating the SQL query.

Comment: there is a way to do what he wants. see answer by Kenney

Comment: The question is unclear, and the answer proposer by Kenney is just a re-writting of a SQL query to make it more readable regarding the where clause.

My assumptions was that he wanted something like "if in select clause, then also in where clause" and that, has to be handle by a piece of code.